# creating a compound field with react-final-form

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

I want to create a compound field (for example **Location** which itself contains 2 inner input `latitude` and `longitude`) with [react-final-form](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form) but I can't find any similar example.

```
<Field name="myField">
  {props => (
    <div>
      <TextField
        name={props.input.name}
        value={props.input.value}
        onChange={props.input.onChange}
      />
    </div>
  )}
</Field>
```

This a simple example with single input, 
My problem is that we have two input and I don't know how to deal with `onChange`.

Comment: Add the code for your use case. With 2 text fields.

Comment: You should do this - `onChange={(value) => props.input.onChange(value)}`

Comment: @ravibagul91 You'r right, I thought onChange accept event only

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your exact requirement, but you can call the same method for onChange on both the TextFields

```
handleLocationChange(partNumber, event) {
  if(partNumber === 1) {
    // handle change to first part of location
  } else {
    // handle change to second part of location
  }
}

render () {
  return <Field name="myField">
    {props => (
      <div>
        <TextField
          name={props.input.name}
          value={props.input.value}
          onChange={this.handleLocationChange.bind(this, 'part1')}
        />
        <TextField
          name={props.input.name}
          value={props.input.value}
          onChange={this.handleLocationChange.bind(this, 'part2')}
        />
      </div>
    )}
  </Field>
}
```

Assuming both your location sections are text, you will probably want to replace `TextField` with `input`

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason that this is not acceptable?

```
<Field name="location.latitude" component="input"/>
<Field name="location.longitude" component="input"/>
```